# free & fast PHP IDE with svn support under OSX?

Tags: php, svn, macos, ide

currently I use eclipse but it is very very slow for few large active projects.

I am not a programmer I use the IDE only for looking up the code or little changes now and then if I do testing.

Eclipse takes soooo much memory and takes time to start up. So exiting after every use is not an option too.

Comment: just installed NetBeans 7.0 and it crashed when reading first project ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Netbeans is very good, and free plus it handles remote project sources via sftp and also supports subversion.  The only downside I find with the latest version (7.0) is that it is very resource-hungry and prone to creaking along.  I get around this by increasing memory in the netbeans.conf file and also by turning off auto-scanning in the preferences->file tab. Hope that helps!

Edit: I've just installed phpStorm. It isn't free but it is worth trying the 30 day trial. It is really fast, lightweight and very quick.

Comment: I tried Netbeans I experienced the same. Very hungry. Can try to tweak it as you did. phpStorm is very good but I don't need it for my everyday  tasks so my boss won't purchase it for me :-(

Comment: well use it for the 30 day trial and when he sees your productivity increase over that time he'll be likely to pay for it! :)

Answer (score 2):

I use xcode. It will give you syntax highlighting, svn and code folding. Some of the most important features, if you ask me. Code completion also works (sometimes)

Comment: Just create a new "blank" project and add you webpage root dir to the project. In xcode svn, is under the SCM name

Answer (score 0):

Even though it's not free, [TextMate](http://macromates.com/) is not really expensive and highly customizable. You have support for Subversion through bundles. It really is from my point of view one of the best code editor on OS X. Version 2 should be there soon.